# twitter-like load more ajax function

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I am trying to add a load more function, but I cannot figure out where to increment the #next# variable.

```
<cfif not isdefined("start")>
<cfset start=1></cfif> 
<cfset perpage=15> <cfset next=start+perpage>

<script type="text/javascript">   
$(function() {      
    $('button').click(function() {
    console.log(<cfoutput>#next#</cfoutput>);       
    $.ajax({            
    type: 'POST',           
    url: '/ajax/tag_group_ajax.cfm',            
    data: 'group=<cfoutput>#group#</cfoutput>&start=<cfoutput>#next#</cfoutput>',                   success: function(html) 
        {
        $('.articleList').append(html);
        <cfset next=next+perpage>
        console.log(<cfoutput>#next#</cfoutput>);           
        }           
        });     
    });     
});  
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear your problem is that you are only incrementing `next` in the ColdFusion code, not the JavaScript. Therefore, every time you click the Load More button, you are loading the same 15 items again and again.

Something like this should help:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
  $(function() {
    var next = <cfoutput>#start#</cfoutput>;

    $('button').click(function() {
      console.log(next);
      next += <cfoutput>#perPage#</cfoutput>;

      $.ajax({            
        type: 'POST',           
        url: '/ajax/tag_group_ajax.cfm',            
        data: 'group=<cfoutput>#group#</cfoutput>&start=' + next, success: function(html)
...
```

Note: I have not tested this code